# GraphQL how to query a polymorphic relation?

Tags: graphql, relationship

Let's say I have a "Dad" entity that could possibly reference one "Son" or "Daughter" entity.

I want to build a graph ql query that will get Dad's name + child' name (Son or Daughter)

```
Dad
 |_Son
or
 |_Daughter
```

I've figured out that using fragments could be a way to go :

```
{
  DadCollection {
    items {
      name
      child {
        __typename
        ...Son{
          name
        }
        ...Daughter{
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Just wonder if there's a more elegant Way to perform the above query avoiding code redundancy,
Or if there's just a better way to get the information

Also... is this a behaviour for graphQL in general or is it due on how this specific graphQL schema server instance was configured to retrieve data?

Comment: What is the schema of the server instance you're talking about? (For the related types)

Comment: @wazner It's a managed system , I dont actually have access to the server or schema definition. But have a GraphiQL UI to query the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This boils down the individual schema.

GraphQL has two *abstract types* -- interfaces and unions. A field may return an abstract type, but that type must always resolve to an object type at runtime. Unions and interfaces are functionally the same except for two differences: 1) Unions define their possible types explicitly, while types have to explicitly implement an interface; and 2) interfaces define a set of common fields that all implementing types must have.

The implication of the latter difference is that when querying an interface field, you don't have to use a fragment to specify a possible type *when querying for shared fields**. In other words, whereas a query on a union field looks like this:

```
query {
  someUnion {
    # no fields allowed outside fragments
    ... on Foo {
      foo
    }
    ... on Bar {
      bar
    }
  }
}
```

a query on an interface field might look like this:

```
query {
  someInterface {
    aCommonField
    anotherCommonField
    ... on Foo {
      foo
    }
    ... on Bar {
      bar
    }
  }
}
```

**However**, it's important to note that just because two types share a field, and both types implement an interface, it doesn't necessarily mean that the field is a field on the interface. It's not enough for fields to be common to do a query like the above -- they have to explicitly be part of the interface's definition.

So whether you can in fact avoid typing `name` for each inline fragment depends on whether 1) the field is an interface and 2) the field in question is part of the interface's definition.

Comment: thanks for the explanation.So... since the query interface is giving me error (looks like common fields aren't allowed). I suppose I'll stick to my original query union w/ fragments. Is there some graphQL syntax to know the type of the field, or I can only go by attempting the query? By graphiQL documentaiton explorer I can see that : Dad's field is child(preview: Boolean, locale: String): DadChild , and that DadChild has possible types Son and Daughter. But it doesn't tell anything about being an interface or a union.

Comment: `DadChild` would list fields in addition to possible types if it was an interface. If no fields are listed, then it's a union.

Comment: I found this interesting article : https://medium.com/commutatus/whats-going-on-with-the-heuristic-fragment-matcher-in-graphql-apollo-client-e721075e92be Where they explain how to run a script that will build fragmentTypes and get back all the details needed.